# NodeJS PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, node.js, post

Всем привет. Такой вопрос, пишу программу на NodeJS. Я в программе привязываю базу данных. Но я не знаю как вывести выводится просто что функция это функция либо undefined. Как решить проблему? Заранее благодарю.

Вот исходник:

```
'use strict'

const pg = require('pg');
const connection = "postgres://lado:1@localhost:5432/public.account";

const client = new pg.Client(connection);
client.connect();
//const queryy = client.query('SELECT * FROM public.account');
//queryy.on('end', () => {client.end(); });

//await client.connect();
const res = client.query("SELECT * FROM account", function(err, rows, fileds) {
   rows.forEach(async function(row) {
       console.log(row.name);
   })
   console.log('Finish');
});

//res.rows.forEach(row=>{
//    console.log(row);
//});

//res.forEach(function(row){
 //    console.log(row);
//});
const func = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
console.dir({func});
console.dir(res);
client.end();
```

Comment: Ошибку покажите

Comment: что то мне подсказывает, что client.query асинхронная функция